# Force join inside of mapping of class

Tags: c#, nhibernate, join, fluent-nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate-mapping

Let's say I have 2 classes, `User` and `Message`

```cs
public class User
{
    public virtual Guid Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
}

public class UserMap : ClassMap<User>, IMappedEntity
{
    public UserMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.Id);
        Map(x => x.Name);
    }
}


public class Message
{
    public virtual Guid Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Text { get; set; }
    public virtual User TheUser { get; set; }
}

public class MessageMap : ClassMap<Message>, IMappedEntity
{
    public MessageMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.Id);
        Map(x => x.Text);
        References<User>(x => x.TheUser)
    }
}
```

When I want to load some Messages, the referenced user has to be loaded as well. As far as I know, nHibernate usually does this by creating a new sql command for every user, causing N+1 problems.

After some research I found this solution which creates a join of the to tables:

```cs
_session.Query<Message>().Fetch(x => x.TheUser)
```

Unfortunately, I can not (easily) implement this, because the logic for accessing data lays inside a generic repository and is used by a lot of other classes as well.

So I would like to know whether there's any possibility to force a join inside of the mapping of my class `Message`.

Comment: Why is the property of the class Message "  public virtual string User { get; set; }" ...... why aren't you doing  "  public virtual User TheUser { get; set; } ...........   Note, I use "The" prefix when proofing NHiberate to avoid ambiguity.

Comment: PS.  I'm "asking"...not "attacking".  Maybe you have a legit reason.  But it looks a little fishy to me.

Comment: It's not only fishy, it's totally wrong ;) I simplified my real mapping and overlooked this. I edited the question, thanks for the hint!

Comment: @granadaCoder: based on my correction, do you have any idea how to solve the problem?

Comment: No, I looked at it.  This one is beyond me.

Answer (score 0):

Should be able to do something like this

```
References<User>(x => x.TheUser)
    .Fetch
    .Join()
```

or

```
References<User>(x => x.TheUser)
    .Fetch
    .Select()
```

Comment: According to NHProf both modifications didn't influence the created SQL query.